# 'Undestroy' an object in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I keep track of deleted objects in an observableArray called 'Deletions'. I parse that array in the UI to create 'undo deletion' links, but I can't get this to work. The code is very straight-forward and looks like this:

```
this.removePage = function(page){
    self.formBuilder.pages.destroy(page);
    var newDeletion = new Deletion();
    newDeletion.element(page);
    self.deletions.push(newDeletion);
}

this.removeFormElement = function(element){
    self.formElements.destroy(element);
    var newDeletion = new Deletion();
    newDeletion.element(element);
    builder.deletions.push(newDeletion);
}

var Deletion = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.element = ko.observable();
};
```

Note that different types of elements can be added to the Deletions observableArray. The only thing I need to do in the 'unremove' function, is setting the 'destroy' flag to false. But, I can't get that to work:

```
this.unremovePage = function(deletion){
    deletion.element()._destroy(false);
}
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

*EDIT*

I can't get this working for the nested FormElements. The structure is: my main ViewModel is called 'FormBuilder'. The FormBuilder has multiple Pages (those are ViewModels themselves) and each Page has multiple FormElements (see code snippet above).

I can 'undelete' those FormElements, but I have no clue how to force a refresh on them.

```
this.unremove = function(deletion){
    //console.log(deletion.element);
    deletion.element()._destroy = false;
    self.deletions.remove(deletion);
    self.formBuilder.pages.valueHasMutated(); // works
    deletion.element().valueHasMutated(); // this doesn't work 
    self.formBuilder.pages.indexOf(deletion.element()).valueHasMutated(); // neither does this
    self.deletions.valueHasMutated(); // works
};
```

- FormBuilder is the main ViewModel;
- FormBuilder has an observableArray called Pages, each Page is a ViewModel;
- Each Page has an observableArray called FormElements, each FormElement is a ViewModel;
- FormBuilder has an observableArray called Deletions, each Deletion is a ViewModel and each Deletion contains an element, either a Page or a FormElement.

The problem:
I use the function 'unremove' to set the 'destroy' property of the element (either Page or FormElement) to false. As you can see, I then call 'valueHasUpdated' on pages. *But how do I call that on the observableArray `formElements` as contained by an individual Page?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_destroy` is not an observable.  So, what you can do it set `_destroy` to false and then call `valueHasMutated` on the observableArray, so that any subscribers (the UI) knows that it may need to make updates.

So, you would want to `deletion.element()._destroy = false;` and then call `self.deletions.valueHasMutated()`.

Comment: Could you please take another look at this? I updated my question.

Comment: Can you put something in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I can't get anything to work on jsFiddle at the moment... I have to strip out too much code... What is it you're looking for? Maybe I can give a better impression by updating the code snippet.

Comment: So, is `unremovePage` called on a page or a formElement?  What are blueprints?  Just not sure the context of your last code snippet.

Comment: I kinda skrewed up the snippet. I renamed stuff to hide the actual case, but didn't do that consequently. I updated the code.

Comment: You need a way to tell what the parent observableArray is for your "deletions".  I would consider adding a parent property to your Deletion objects that is the observableArray and then call `valueHasMutated` on the deletion's parent in your `unremove` method.

Comment: How do I know what the parent is in 'removeFormElement'? I only have the element itself there (the object FormElement), but I don't know how to know which parent it belongs to.

Comment: By the way, I really respect your effort!

Comment: It looks like you are calling `self.formElements.destroy` already in that method, which shouldn't work with the structure that you have described. You could place `removeFormElement` as a function on the `Page` objects, then `self.formElements` would be the parent.

Comment: That kind of works. removeFormElement is a function in Page now, and I set the parent page on Deletion. Then, in the unremove function, I get this: `deletion.parent().valueHasMutated is not a function`. I'm not sure what's wrong there. When I use log() to show `deletion.parent` it shows it's a Page, so the object is in there. Why can't I call the function?

Comment: Couldn't get this to work with valueHasMutated, so I push an empty element (self.formElements.push();) and then it updates the UI. Thanks a bunch for your endless effort (on all Knockout questions here ;) ).

Comment: Is `parent` an observable itself.  If it is just a property set to the observableArray, then you would want to call `deletion.parent.valueHasMutated`

Comment: Parent is an observable, yeah.